# Magento2 Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreManager' not found

Tags: magento2, multistore

I moved my Magento2.2.5 based website to a new server (its a multisite) and now I am getting this error when trying to go to the website and note sure why

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreManager' not found in /index.php:46
```

My index file looks like this

```
switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
case 'www.abc.de':
case 'abc.de':
    $params = $_SERVER; $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'de';
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store';
    $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
    $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
    $bootstrap->run($app);
    break;
default:
    Mage::run();
break;
}
```

Comment: Mage::run()? and what is the line of '/index.php:46'?